# Visual Basic PowerPacks from 2010 not working in 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have been using Visual Studio 2010 on my old computer, and I have used PowerPack shapes in my designer. In VS2013, I have installed the PowerPacks but it keeps complaining that it cannot find anything related.

`Type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer' is not defined.`

This is happening for OvalShape and a few others, not just this. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Can you see the powerpack items in your toolbox ?

Comment: how did you install them?, what steps did you use.

Comment: I followed this: http://ntcoder.com/bab/2013/12/20/visualbasic-powerpack-missing-from-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Are the errors in a preexisting project that you made in vs2010 and are trying to use in vs2013 or in a new project created in vs2013?

Comment: From an existing project made in vs2010.

Comment: If you go to your solution explorer and click on your project, then click on the Show All files Icon you will see a references section, pen it up and let me know if you have any icons saying if any references are missing.

Comment: There's a little yellow exclamation mark icon next to "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like your program is not able to find the reference to your VisualBasic PowerPack extension. Try right clicking on References select add reference then goto Assemblys --> Extensions scroll down and find the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS` Reference remove the checkmark there and select the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` reference and click ok, that should fix it for you. You probably will also need to remove the reference that has the yellow exclamation mark.

It looks like the extension's name has changed from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS` to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks`. Since I have both VS2010 and VS2013 on my laptop I show both of them.

[image]

Comment: @MarkHall Mine is black out/hidden! Why is this i'm using VB language